# SonarQube Unit Tests drilldown not populated

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, mstest, dotcover

I'm configuring SonarQube 5.2 runner from TeamCity 9.1.4, but the Unit Test success widget is not being populated anyway. Could you guys give some hints, please?

I have already tried a lot of things, like use "generic reports plugin" that works with xml files, instead of the html that i'm using now, but no success... :(

[image]

BUILD LOG:

```
[15:05:39] : Step 1/2: dotCoverage Export (Command Line) (32s)
[15:05:40]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation' value='297.0']
[15:05:40]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_126' value='0.0']
[15:05:40] :     [Step 1/2] Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe report /ReportType=HTML /Source=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Publish\dotCover.dcvr /Output=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Publish\dotCover.html
[15:05:40] :     [Step 1/2] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices
[15:05:40] :     [Step 1/2] JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 10. Build 104.0.20151101.190849
[15:05:40] :     [Step 1/2] Copyright (c) 2009-2015 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
[15:05:42] :     [Step 1/2] [JetBrains dotCover] Report generation started [19/11/2015 15:05:42]
[15:06:11] :     [Step 1/2] [JetBrains dotCover] Report generation finished [19/11/2015 15:06:11]
[15:06:12] :     [Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
[15:06:12]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_126' value='31988.0']
[15:06:12] : Step 2/2: SonarQube Analysis (SonarQube Runner) (1m:03s)
[15:06:12]i:     [Step 2/2] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_125' value='0.0']
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] Starting SQR
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -DFxCopCmdFileVersion=10.0.30319.1
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -DFxCopRoot=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dagent.home.dir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dagent.name=SERVER1
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dagent.work.dir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dbuild.number=34
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=226
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9090/RPC2
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=4232
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.auth.password=Ewt5A7XXyi4pg50pBHMetfbHqjG5HBva
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=4232
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\changedFiles9108058098304491619.txt
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.build8545992613604428050.properties
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.buildConfName=QA SonarQube
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.buildType.id=MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao_QaSonarQube
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.config8398983358343943641.properties
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitAddin-NUnit
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher1.1=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher1.1.exe
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.exe
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0.vsts=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.VSTS.exe
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.dotnet.platform=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.1.1.exe
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.projectName=Desenvolvimento / Homologação
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.runner.properties.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.runner2807709705695945066.properties
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\testsToRunFirst4650244966672362721.txt
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dteamcity.version=9.1.4 (build 37293)
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -classpath
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\sonar-plugin-agent\sonar-qube-runner\lib\sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] org.sonar.runner.Main
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.projectKey=MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.projectName=MATRIX.API
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.projectVersion=34
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.sources=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.tests=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api.Test
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.binaries=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Build\Release\bin\
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao_319.393"
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] -Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Publish\dotCover.html"
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] Starting: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" -DFxCopCmdFileVersion=10.0.30319.1 "-DFxCopRoot=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0" -Dagent.home.dir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent -Dagent.name=SERVER1 -Dagent.work.dir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work -Dbuild.number=34 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=226 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9090/RPC2 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=4232 -Dteamcity.auth.password=Ewt5A7XXyi4pg50pBHMetfbHqjG5HBva -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=4232 -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\changedFiles9108058098304491619.txt -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.build8545992613604428050.properties -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices "-Dteamcity.buildConfName=QA SonarQube" -Dteamcity.buildType.id=MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao_QaSonarQube -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.config8398983358343943641.properties -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitAddin-NUnit -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher1.1=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher1.1.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0.vsts=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.VSTS.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.platform=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.1.1.exe -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\testsToRunFirst4650244966672362721.txt "-Dteamcity.version=9.1.4 (build 37293)" -Dsonar.projectKey=MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao -Dsonar.projectName=MATRIX.API -Dsonar.projectVersion=34 -Dsonar.sources=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api -Dsonar.tests=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api.Test -Dsonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao_319.393" -Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Publish\dotCover.html"
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] SonarQube Runner 2.4
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] Java 1.8.0_65 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: Runner configuration file: NONE
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: Work directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\.\.sonar
[15:06:12] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: SonarQube Server 5.2
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.033 INFO  - Load global repositories
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.515 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=436ms
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.536 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. There is no more DB connection to the SQ database. It will be ignored.
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.537 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. There is no more DB connection to the SQ database. It will be ignored.
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.538 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. There is no more DB connection to the SQ database. It will be ignored.
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.539 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\buildexec\.sonar\cache
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.907 INFO  - Load plugins index
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.913 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=6ms
[15:06:16] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:16.934 INFO  - Plugin [l10npt] defines 'l10nen' as base plugin. This metadata can be removed from manifest of l10n plugins since version 5.2.
[15:06:17] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:17.317 INFO  - Process project properties
[15:06:18] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:18.660 INFO  - Load project repositories
[15:06:19] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:19.994 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=1334ms
[15:06:20] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:20.067 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
[15:06:20] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:20.334 INFO  - Load quality profiles
[15:06:21] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:21.326 INFO  - Load quality profiles (done) | time=992ms
[15:06:21] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:21.383 INFO  - Load active rules
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.300 INFO  - Load active rules (done) | time=917ms
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.327 INFO  - Publish mode
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.329 INFO  - -------------  Scan MATRIX.API
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.491 INFO  - Load server rules
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.832 INFO  - Load server rules (done) | time=341ms
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.960 INFO  - Base dir: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.960 INFO  - Working dir: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\.sonar
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.963 INFO  - Source paths: MATRIX.Api
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.963 INFO  - Test paths: MATRIX.Api.Test
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.963 INFO  - Binary dirs: Build/Release/bin
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.964 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.965 INFO  - Index files
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.977 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
[15:06:22] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:22.977 INFO  -   **/bin/**
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.814 WARN  - Invalid character encountered in file D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api.Test\bin\Release\Microsoft.Owin.xml at line 2168 for encoding windows-1252. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.853 WARN  - Invalid character encountered in file D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIX.Api.Test\bin\Release\System.Net.Http.Formatting.xml at line 1701 for encoding windows-1252. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.921 INFO  - 241 files indexed
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.922 INFO  - 92 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.942 INFO  - Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
[15:06:23] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:23.943 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.027 INFO  - All ReSharper rules are disabled, skipping its execution.
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.035 INFO  - All StyleCop rules are disabled, skipping its execution.
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.038 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.038 WARN  - Sonargraph: Skipping projectMATRIX.API [MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.038 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.039 INFO  - All FxCop rules are disabled, skipping its execution.
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.071 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.120 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=49ms
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.121 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.127 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=6ms
[15:06:24] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:24.127 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor
[15:06:25] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:25.258 INFO  - SonarLint for Visual Studio version 1.3.0.0
[15:06:26] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:26.770 INFO  - 0/207 files analyzed, starting to analyze:
(207 files properly analyzed)
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.125 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor (done) | time=32998ms
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.126 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.151 INFO  - Aggregating the HTML reports from D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\Publish\dotCover.html

[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.306 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor (done) | time=180ms
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.307 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.307 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MATRIXServices\MATRIXServices_DesenvolvimentoHomologacao_319.393
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.365 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor (done) | time=58ms
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.365 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.367 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: svn
[15:06:57] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:57.372 INFO  - 21 files to be analyzed
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.245 INFO  - 0/21 files analyzed
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  - Missing blame information for the following files:
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Autofac.Integration.Owin.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Owin.Security.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Http.WebHost.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.WebPages.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/MATRIX.Api.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Http.Owin.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Autofac.Integration.WebApi.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Autofac.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Mvc.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Helpers.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Owin.Cors.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Owin.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Net.Http.Formatting.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Razor.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  -   * D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/MATRIXServices/MATRIX.Api.Test/bin/Release/System.Web.Http.xml
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 WARN  - This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.246 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1881ms
[15:06:59] :     [Step 2/2] 15:06:59.248 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
[15:07:02] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:02.221 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=2974ms
[15:07:02] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:02.221 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
[15:07:02] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:02.221 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for cs
[15:07:02] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:02.675 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for xml
[15:07:02] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:02.675 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=454ms
[15:07:05] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:05.407 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 2678ms, dir size=6 MB
[15:07:09] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:09.198 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 3791ms, zip size=1 MB
[15:07:09] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:09.569 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 369ms
[15:07:09] :     [Step 2/2] Publishing artifacts (4s)
[15:07:09] :         [Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\sonar_server.txt=>.teamcity/sonar/]
[15:07:13] :         [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file [D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/sonar_server.txt => .teamcity/sonar] using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[15:07:13] :         [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file [D:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/sonar_server.txt => .teamcity/sonar] using [WebPublisher]
[15:07:09] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:09.578 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
[15:07:09] :     [Step 2/2] 15:07:09.578 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] Total time: 1:02.745s
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] Final Memory: 10M/273M
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:07:15] :     [Step 2/2] Process exited with code 0
[15:07:15]i:     [Step 2/2] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_125' value='63721.0']

[15:07:19]i: ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildFinishing' value='3626.0']
[15:07:19] : Publishing internal artifacts
[15:07:19] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[15:07:19] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[15:07:19]i: ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:artifactsPublishing' value='281.0']
[15:07:19] : Build finished
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you have both code coverage and unit test results on your dashboard. The SonarQube C# Plugin does not yet allow to drilldown on the unit test result numbers, which I suspect is what you are looking for. There already is a ticket to improve this in the future: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-17

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. For example, on this page: [http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/219971](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/219971) all the numbers are "clickable", and leads the user to another page with more information (drilldown).

Thanks for your answer!